# Anyone know of any parallelizing compilers following the approach of the Dragon Book?

Tags: compiler, parallelism

In [*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools*, Aho *et al*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321486811) describe an approach for optimizing for parallelism (chapter 11 in the second edition). Is anyone aware of any existing compilers which follow that approach?

Comment: Maybe everyone and her aunt knows the book, but still how bout providing some quote(s) to establish some context?

Comment: jaffachief please ignore @Martin. _Real_ programmers know the Dragon Book by heart.

Comment: @Zaphod, I am afraid some scamster may have fooled you into believing he would be a Real Programmer. Everyone knows that Real Programmers scorn on pathetic compiled programs and prefer hex editing the machine code directly instead. ([Obligatory XKCD reference](http://xkcd.com/378/))

Comment: @PéterTörök I read the first version of the comment, and was surprised it didn't mention butterflies. But, then a second notification appear, and order was restored. Well played :)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox, [this](http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Compiler-Addison-Wesley-information-processing/dp/0201000229/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1326994053&sr=1-1) is the Dragon book known by heart by real programmer. And AFAIR (sadly, I'm not ARealProgrammer, just AProgrammer :-), there is no suggestion of an approach for optimizing for parallelism in it.

Comment: @AProgrammer AFAIK _real_ programmers stay up to date. When you finish memorizing the _current_ edition, there's a second edition of the Wizard book, in case you missed that too :P

Comment: @AProgrammer That's the real one I remember.  I think I got it back in 1983 or so.  I remember I was still in high school...

Comment: Different compilers will implement some of the Chapter 11 optimizations. Many compilers implement optimizations not discussed in Chapter 11. Is there a specific optimization you are most interested in?

Comment: Dragon Book is outdated. It won't mention anything of the most recent stuff - SSA-based optimisations, polyhedral models, etc.

Comment: It does mention polyhedral models actually. Chapter 11 (of the second edition) deals with them fairly rigorously

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any first-hand experience with it, nor do I know whether the techniques used are in the Dragon Book to the letter, but the [Sun Studio C and C++ compilers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html) can do automatic parallellization of `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer directly that question, regarding parallelism or concurrency, but, the Dragon Book was written some decades ago, with some updates, maybe, and Compiler Techniques have change a lot.

I have read some compilers docs, on the internet, and some of them use different ideas.

Besides, there are other books & (online) publications about compilers, that try to "kill the dragon", each one in a different way.